# no python27.dll to copy into Scripts directory

Tags: flask

I have installed python2.7.3 in d:\Python27\python  ,and 
mkdir in g:\microblog, downloaded virtualenv.py in  g:\microblog,when 
cd into g:microblog, i want to install flask in the g:\microblog to do it as the web 
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

```
g:\microblog>d:\Python27\python  virtualenv.py flask
Overwriting flask\lib\orig-prefix.txt with new content
New python executable in flask\Scripts\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\microblog\flask\lib\site.py", line 67, in <module>
    import os
  File "g:\microblog\flask\lib\os.py", line 397
    yield from walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ERROR: The executable flask\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'g:\\microblog' (should be u'g:\\microblog\\flas
k')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python for
 "Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the app
ropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this problem.
```

I can not find Python27.dll in my D:\Python27\DLLs

```
 Directory of D:\Python27\DLLs

08/18/2014  09:36 AM    <DIR>          .
08/18/2014  09:36 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            59,904 bz2.pyd
03/08/2011  09:39 AM            19,790 py.ico
03/08/2011  09:39 AM            19,790 pyc.ico
04/10/2012  11:31 PM           103,424 pyexpat.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM             9,728 select.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM           337,920 sqlite3.dll
08/28/2010  02:42 PM           867,840 tcl85.dll
08/28/2010  02:42 PM             8,192 tclpip85.dll
08/28/2010  02:45 PM         1,320,448 tk85.dll
04/10/2012  11:31 PM           686,592 unicodedata.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM             8,704 winsound.pyd
04/10/2012  11:32 PM           877,056 _bsddb.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            74,240 _ctypes.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            13,824 _ctypes_test.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            70,656 _elementtree.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM           285,184 _hashlib.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            46,080 _msi.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            23,552 _multiprocessing.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            40,960 _socket.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            41,984 _sqlite3.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM           721,920 _ssl.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            29,184 _testcapi.pyd
04/10/2012  11:31 PM            30,208 _tkinter.pyd
              23 File(s)      5,697,180 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   5,159,092,224 bytes free
```

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is in `c:/windows/system32/python27.dll`